# Sed command is making changes to the original script

Tags: bash

Can anyone suggest that how do I make sure that a particular command in shell script not effect the script from which it is called? For example in my case I am replacing all occurrences of a particular word with some other word, using "sed" command. But I don't want this to do changing in the original script.

Comment: `sed` does in-place changes with the `-i` option so you could just omit that option assuming that is what you are doing.  Please show us your script.

Comment: You are having sed operate on the script that is running the sed command?

Comment: Probably by writing better, less lazy code, that explicitly names exactly what files you want it to operate on, rather than overusing wildcards and other generalizations that have the potential to occasionally match things that you don't intend them to match...

Comment: Do you call your sed for a bunch of files? Make sure your script is not one of them. `chmod -w` or `grep -v yourscript` are bad work-arounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `basename $0` in your script.
For example for current directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="*"
CURRENT=`basename $0`
for f in $FILES
do
  if [ -f $f ] && [ $f != $CURRENT ]
  then
    #some sed action with file
  fi
done
```